# eslint: ignore-pattern rule is not working

Tags: node.js, eslint

I have the following structure

```
myproject
    src
        indxe.js
```

In my package.json  I have also :

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d dist --source-maps",
    "serve": "node dist/index.js",
    "start": "babel-node src/index.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon src/index.js --exec babel-node",
    "test": "jest --runInBand --verbose",
    "coverage": "jest --coverage --runInBand --verbose",
    "eslint": "eslint src/**/.js --ignore-pattern \"node_modules/\""
  },
```

but running

```
yarn eslint
```

I get an error

```
"eslint": "eslint src/**/.js --ignore-pattern \"node_modules/\""

$ eslint src/**/.js --ignore-pattern "node_modules/"

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 5.10.0.
No files matching the pattern "src/**/.js" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.

error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

I don't understand why as it should be OK...

feedback welcome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You specified the glob pattern incorrectly:

```
eslint src/**/.js
```

With this, you are specifying: “In any directory below *src*, find me any files with the **exact name** *.js*”

What you actually want is: “In any directory below *src*, find me any files with the **name ending in** *.js*”

You can achieve this by adding another asterisk, which serves as placeholder for the beginning of each JS file name, like this:

```
eslint src/**/*.js
```

You can find more information on how to use glob patterns here: https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#readme